# why doesnt bash output stdout when used with $(command)?

Tags: python, bash

If I write a script in bash like

```
!/bin/bash
python run_script.py
```

I will get the data echoed by the python script, but if I use

```
!/bin/bash
$(python run_script.py)
```

I can't  get any output. So, how can I show outputs using the second example?

Answer (score 5):

The whole point of `$()` is to capture the output of the command.

If you want to display it as well, just `echo` it:

```
#!/bin/bash
output=$(python run_script.py)
echo "$output"
```

Using `$(command)` executes the command in a sub-shell and captures the result. Look up [command substitution](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_03) to learn more about that.

To be clear, it is unnecessary to use `$()` in the script I have shown; if you don't need to use the result of executing the python command, you don't need a command substitution here.

Comment: useless use of `$()`.

Comment: In this tiny example, yes!

Comment: Hm, I thought the point of `$(python foo.py)` was to run it as a bash command. I never knew that. .

Comment: The whole point of `bash` is simply to run commands, which is why you only have to type `python run_script.py` at the prompt instead of something like `run python run_script.py`. The simplicity of that task is why nearly everything else in `bash` seems unnecessarily complicated.